# Запись переменной через кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Можете подсказать, как можно по нажатию кнопки записать данные в переменную? Точнее, насколько обработчик этой кнопки будет большой, или это можно будет сделать в аргументах кнопки. Или мне попробовать это реализовать через callback_data, которые можно будет перезаписывать? У меня всплывает много вариантов решения этой "сложной" задачи, но не могу понять как будет правильнее

Код:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="vipcount")
async def vipcount(query: CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text=1, callback_data="buyvip"), #<--- эта кнопка должна поставить в переменную какое-либо значение
        InlineKeyboardButton(text=2, callback_data="buyvip"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text=3, callback_data="buyvip")
    )
    await query.message.edit_text(text, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Обработчик, который будет использовать эти переменные планируется реализовать отдельно, не в этой функции. Заранее спасибо за помощь

p.s. пишу на уставшую голову. если что-то надо будет объяснить подробнее - на связи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из задачи вам нужно что-то типо этого.

```
#Клавиатуру сделай так
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).add(
    InlineKeyboardButton(text=1, callback_data="buyvip:1"), #<--- эта кнопка должна поставить в переменную какое-либо значение
    InlineKeyboardButton(text=2, callback_data="buyvip:2"),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text=3, callback_data="buyvip:3")
)

variable = 0

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="buyvip")
async def buyvip(query: CallbackQuery):
    await query.answer()
    global variable
    variable = int(query.data.split(":")[1])
```

Comment: Есть три кнопки - 1;2;3. Эти две кнопки созданы для выбора количества билетов. Т.е если человек нажмет на "2" - в переменную задастся 2. Если 3 - то 3 и т.д

Comment: Обновил проверяй

Comment: Большое спасибо!